# How to to convert LTE SIM data to eSIM (as a carrier)?

Tags: telecommunication

I'm running a private 4g LTE network and currently using physical SIM cards.
Since I have access to all of the data on the SIM card I'm wondering how I can create an eSIM using that information? Is it simply a file type in a certain format?

Once I have that file there shouldn't be a problem downloading into the ohone. Does anyone have info on this? Everything I try and research on it I gives me carrier specific info, but since I'm the carrier that's kind of worthless lol.⁸